# Parsing element text with capybara-webkit

Tags: ruby, regex, web-scraping, capybara, capybara-webkit

I'm new to Ruby and Capybara and I'm trying to use capybara-webkit to scrape a website. All of the data I'm interested in lies in `td` tags with certain properties.

Where `form` is a particular form element I'm looking at, the following code works:

```
form.all('td').detect do |td|
  if td['valign'] == 'top' && td['nowrap'] != 'nowrap'
    print "#{td.text}\n"
  end
end
```

The contents of all of the `td` elements I'm interested in are printed out correctly. However, when I try to then parse the text with a regex:

```
form.all('td').detect do |td|
  if td['valign'] == 'top' && td['nowrap'] != 'nowrap'
    print "#{td.text}\n"
    val1, val2 = td.match(/(\d)(\d)/).captures # The real regex is more complex
  end
end
```

...suddenly only the first `td` element is read/parsed. I've tried even just pushing each `td.text` value into an array for later parsing, but the same thing occurs. I've even tried making a clone of the `td.text` string and operating on that—no luck. There doesn't seem to be any sort of timeout on the page that would change the HTML elements. Absolutely no clue what could be causing this.

Any thoughts?